# What type of relationship is this for a Class Diagram

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram

I have a class Employee and  a class Mananger. Manager has the same abilities and attributes as employee but more functionality, is this association?

Comment: See http://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical case of Generalization with Employee being the superclass and Manager as a subclass.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your feedback, why in UML is the arrow the same for generalization and inheritance?

Comment: Because it's semantically the same thing. You inherit from something general and make it more rich. Like in real life - hopefully.